# In Scala, would the following pattern match prevent excessive garbage collection?

Tags: scala

I'm doing some heavy database processing and am getting the error message

> GC overhead limit exceeded

Caused by

> ResultSet getString

In my code I have checks such as the following

```
val myVal = result.getString("COLUMN")
if (myVal == ...) {}
```

What I'm wondering is if I change this

```
result.getString("COLUMN") match {
case ...
}
```

Does this save a variable from having to be created and garbage collected?  Or is this some internal mechanism which means that this happens anyway?

Edit: result is a JDBC ResultSet

Comment: If you think garbage collection is about variables, you should refresh your understanding of GC. A variable is just a name tag pointing to an object. Either way: More code, in particular details on what's `result`, may help people helping.

Comment: I'd say the proposed change changes nothing since the objects need to be created to be comparable nevertheless. You should do some profiling to isolate the parts of your code that create lots of objects. It might be worth trying to do the data processing in your database instead of your Scala code to avoid transferring database contents to objects within the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not prevent object allocation. The object is allocated by `getString`, not by `val myVal =`. What it *may* do is free the object sooner, since it will eligible for garbage collection as soon as no one reference it. If you have a `myVal` pointing to it, that won't happen until `myVal` goes out of scope.

This may help you, since very short lived objects are very cheap to garbage collect. But, truth to be told, it seems unlikely.